# Visual Studio 2013: Link ComboBox values to Textbox data

Tags: c#, combobox

Ok, let me try to explain this as simply as possible, and then move on with more details if it's necessary.

What I currently have is a set of Textboxes that data is entered into. I want to be able to use a ComboBox to let a user choose between each of these entries (so it can be "assigned" to a label in a different spot in my program).

I have six textboxes with entries in them, and I want to be able to have six ComboBoxes that picks from those Textbox entries, but have each Textbox only assigned to one ComboBox.

So, let's say ComboBox1 takes the value assigned to TextBox1. I want to make it so that ComboBox 2 cannot also select the value of TextBox1, but has to choose between the five remaining TextBoxes.

Is there a way to do this? If any more details are needed, let me know, and I will reply back with as much info as I can. Thank you!

EDIT: I love how people downvote me for no good reason. I'm new to programming, which is why I'm here to learn! I'm sorry if this is something simple, I just haven't seen anything like it on my own yet, and googling has come up with nothing similar enough for me to work from!

Comment: There is absolutely a way to do this, but it will be a lot easier to help you if you post the code you have so far. ;)

Comment: This can all be done very easily in the code behind which will take some effort on your end.. have you started any coding..? if not please do not expect others to do the work for you especially being that this is so `NON TRIVIAL`

Comment: I've done coding in other places in my form. I know how to do a lot of little stuff, but I don't have a lot of depth of experience yet. Since I'm trying to self-teach as I go along, it's kind of hard to find examples of specific use cases of what I'm doing...

Comment: @daftinquisitor _it's kind of hard to find examples of specific use cases of what I'm doing_ and that's your main problem. You're expecting to find something (or someone) that tells you exactly what to do in your specific case, and when learning, that only happens with very basic and trivial stuff. Instead, try to split your problem into smaller, simplier problems, solve them with what you already know and search for those specific little things you yet don't know.

Comment: Well, it took me two days of staring at the problem just to figure out I'm able to move the "ComboBox.Items.AddRange" item from the Form.Designer.cs view to the Form.cs view itself, and then call it to add the info to it after it's been put in the text boxes. If someone would have just told me that much, I could have figured out the first half of the problem a lot more quickly.

I'm not here looking for a fix-all, I'm here looking for nudges about things I just plain don't know about.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Ok, after digging a bit, I FINALLY managed to figure out how to add the values from the TextBoxes to the ComboBox (using a separate button to create an "apply" function so the program knew the boxes were ready to draw values from). However, I'm still trying to figure out how to get it to make each value assignable to only one ComboBox.

This part is going to be harder, I can tell already. I'll keep working and update with any progress.